# Oozie - Change Date time format

Tags: xml, hadoop, timezone, oozie

As a newbie with Oozie, I try to run some tutorials. Here is my bundle xml file:

```
--<bundle-app name='MyProject' xmlns='uri:oozie:bundle:0.2'> 
        <controls>
       <kick-off-time>2016-08-22T04:00+0200</kick-off-time>
    </controls>
    <coordinator name='wramUp' >
        <app-path>${projectRoot}/oozie/coordinator/coordinator.xml</app-path>
    </coordinator>
</bundle-app>--
```

Running within HUE interface, I've got this error:

> Error submitting job /project/oozie/bundle/bundle.xml
>
> E1310: Bundle Job submission Error: [E1301: Could not read the bundle
>   job definition, [Could not parse [2016-08-22T04:00+0200] using
>   [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'] mask]]

It seems that the time zone format on my server is not compatible with input date time within my bundle file. Without modifying my bundle file, i would like to know if I can modify Oozie configuration to run my job.

Thanks all in advance!